# Generate map of natural id as key and string as value from list of string in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Suppose i have a list of string

```
List<String> fourthList = Arrays.asList("abc","def","ghi");
```

I want to convert it  into Map like **{1=abc,2=def,3=ghi}**.

Collectors in java is not allowing to me do that as it accept method only in keyMapper .

Comment: This question has not been asked before or maybe i haven't found it. i was able to find convert list to map however in all the questions it mentioned user type variables .i was concerned about List of String type only .

Comment: Map<Integer, String> collect = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, fourthList.size() - 1)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i + 1, fourthList::get));
        System.out.println(collect);

Answer (score 2):

As Per [Hadi J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3669698/hadi-j)'s comment (*recommended*) you can use use :

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, list.size() - 1) 
         .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, String>(i + 1, list.get(i))) 
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

---

**Another way-around**:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "ghi");
```

Converting `List` to `Map<Integer, String>` with key as integer and starting with `0...n`:

```
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
Map<Integer, String> map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> index.incrementAndGet(), Function.identity()));
map.forEach((l, m) -> System.out.println(l + "  " + m));
```

**Output:**

```
1  abc
2  def
3  ghi
```

I had done similar Map practices earlier this year, you can have a look: https://github.com/vishwaratna/ThatsHowWeDoItInJava8/blob/master/src/ListToMapWIthKeyAsInteger.java

Comment: The problem is your use of a static variable `k` makes this non-thread-safe, among many other drawbacks.

Comment: Thread safety is not a concern for me now , anyways Its good catch.

Comment: Thanks Vishwa it worked , however i have doubt on toMap signature as it accepts Function as argument however here it is taking variable here

Comment: @RahulPyasi , you are right `toMap` signature accepts *Function* . **Java lambda** expressions are Java's first step into functional programming. *A Java lambda expression is thus a **function** which can be created without belonging to any class.*

Comment: @VishwaRatna This is clear explanation . thanks for info!

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, list.size()).mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i + 1, list.get(i)))...` could have read bettter.